# How to specify Default agent pool in azure devops create pipeline API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to automate pipeline creationg, however every pipeline is created without a Default agent pool specified, and therefore it cant run, what do i add in the api body to specify the queue id of the agent ?

below is my request body

```
          pipeline_json='{
            "configuration": {
              "type": "yaml",
              "path": "/'$(basename $templateFilePath .yaml).yml'",
              "repository": {
                "type": "azureReposGit",
                "id": "'"$repoId"'",
                "name": "'${{ parameters.repoName }}'",
                "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/master"
              }
            },
            "folder": "'"$pipeline_folder"'",
            "name": "'"$pipeline_name"'"
          }'
```

This calls other templates in which inside there are multiple jobs and each job calls its own pool, i just need to specify a queue id somehow when calling the api, i tried adding pool myself but it didnt help either.

i have tried to use the AZ CLI which give u the option to add a queue id which solves the problem however due to other authentication issues (the az cli request a token to authenticate) i have to use the api.

there's not trace of the queue id being mentioned in the api documentation either.

Comment: Did you set agent pool in your yaml definition?

Comment: i did for some reason it doesnt work. the default agent is always not set. i didn writes the pipelines myself but they use other pools in some of the steps maybe they conflict.

Comment: Could you show this yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using the azure create DEFINITION api instead of pipeline, this allows you to specify the queue id in the request ! or else you can use the azure CLI to create pipelines they also provide the queue parameter